# Rails how to render first and call method after?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this action in my controller:

```
def ad

    @koder = @side.reklamers.pluck(:id) - [session[:log]]
    @reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
    session[:log] = @reklame.id
    render :text => "<span class='bannerid' data-id='#{@reklame.id}'></span><p style='margin-bottom: 7px;margin-top: 7px;font-size: 9px;text-align: center !important;'>Ad</p>#{@reklame.kode}"

 end
```

It renders an HTML ad. This code is really fast. The problem is when I do try to example count view the response becomes VERY slow. 3s. Compared to 200ms!

```
@koder = @side.reklamers.pluck(:id) - [session[:log]]
@reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
session[:log] = @reklame.id
@reklame.views += 1
@reklame.save
render :text => "<span class='bannerid' data-id='#{@reklame.id}'></span><p style='margin-bottom: 7px;margin-top: 7px;font-size: 9px;text-align: center !important;'>Ad</p>#{@reklame.kode}"
```

I have tried to add a resque background job with the same result..

What should I do?

Comment: maybe you should provide the code of your attempt to use a background-job solution.

Comment: I did just try to call one of my already existing background jobs and it slowed the response by 2,8s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `views` is really a counter maybe you should take a look at:

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/increment_counter

In your case it should look like this

```
Reklamer.increment_counter(:views, @reklame.id)
```

It should update only views column, don't run validations, callbacks etc. which will make it faster. But on the other hand 3s on simple save indicates that there is something else going wrong also.

Answer (score 0):

First, try:

```
@reklame.update_attribute :views, @reklame.views + 1
```

See if that helps.  If so, then you have some costly data validations going on that are slowing you down, but at least you know the source of the problem.

If that doesn't work, try wrapping that statement in

```
Thread.new { //code }
```

If it's still slow doing the save, then it's probably how your database is set up or something along those lines.